# Chernoff vs Berry-Esseen

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems, large-deviation-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be iid random variables with mean $\mu > 0$, variance $\sigma^2$ and $X_i \in [-1,1]$ for all $i$. Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Suppose $l < h < 0$. I am trying to upper bound the probability of $P[l \leq S_n \leq h]$. Of course I can use Chernoff bound as follows :
\begin{align*}
P[l \leq S_n \leq h] \leq P[S_n \leq h] = P[S_n \leq (1 - \delta)n\mu] \leq e^{-\delta^2 n \mu^2/2}
\end{align*}
Where $\delta = 1 - \frac{h}{n\mu}$. Substituting this value of $\delta$ gives a bound of $O(e^{-n\mu^2})$ when $n$ is large enough.

Let $T_n = \frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}$. Then we have 
\begin{align*}
P[l \leq S_n \leq h] = P\left[\frac{l-n\mu}{\sqrt{n}} \leq T_n \leq \frac{h - n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}\right] = F_{T_n}(\frac{h - n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}) - F_{T_n}({\frac{l-n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}})}
\end{align*}

Since $T_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$, I can ``use'' the central limit theorem.

Let $\rho = E[|X_1 - \mu|^3]$. Then Berry-Esseen theorem states that $\forall x$, $\left|F_{T_n}(x) - \Phi(x)\right| \leq \frac{3\rho}{\sigma^3 \sqrt{n}}$. Using this theorem, we have for any $x < y$,

\begin{align*}
&\left|F_{T_n}(y) - F_{T_n}(x) - \int_{x}^{y} \phi(t) dt\right| \leq \frac{6 \rho}{\sigma^3 \sqrt{n}} \\
&\Rightarrow F_{T_n}(y) - F_{T_n}(x) \leq \int_{x}^{y} \phi(t) dt + O(1/\sqrt{n})
\end{align*}

Now, substituting $y = (h - n\mu)/\sigma\sqrt{n}$ and $x = (l - n\mu)/\sigma\sqrt{n}$ we get
\begin{align*}
&P[l \leq S_n \leq h] \leq  \int_{(l-n\mu)/\sigma \sqrt{n}}^{(h - n\mu)/\sigma \sqrt{n}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} dt + O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
&\leq \frac{h-l}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(h-n\mu)^2}{2n\sigma^2}} + O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
\end{align*}

For large enough $n$, the upper bound on the contribution from the integral is $O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-n\mu^2/2\sigma^2} )$. However, the error term of $O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ overwhelms it.

I am curious to know whether a bound of the form $O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-cn})$ for some constant $c > 0$ can be proven formally, or the bound of $O(e^{-cn})$ derived by Chernoff Inequality is the best achievable.

Comment: The identity between a probability and an integral in the question, is wrong (and not what the CLT says).

Comment: Could you please explain where I am wrong? Is your concern the following : $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P[(S_n - n\mu)/\sqrt{n} \leq z] = \Phi(z/\sigma)$ only when $z$ is a constant and does not vary with $n$.

Comment: Yes, that. And the fact that $S_n$ need not be gaussian.

Comment: In fact, $O(e^{-cn}) = O(e^{-c'n}/\sqrt{n})$ for any $c'<c$. So yes, this can be proved.